# Working Vue 3 app empties mounted element when using Vue as an npm package

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with a very simple Vue 3 app, listed below.

This works like a charm when including Vue as a script, see code snippet.

I need to use it with webpack however, and therefore include it as an npm package.
In this case the app loads, but Vue empties everything inside the div it's mounted on.
See [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/webpack-vue-3-forked-y5c6j?file=/src/main.js)

I've tried different ways to export and import the App object, but none work.
What am I overlooking?

```js
const {ref} = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    const inc = () => {
      count.value++;
    };

    return {count, inc};
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#simple-example')
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="simple-example">
    <h1>Hello Vue 3!</h1>
    <button @click="inc">Clicked {{ count }} times.</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It says what's wrong in the console, `[Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing this:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
```

into this:

```
import { createApp } from "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler";
```

fixed the problem. Thanks to [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask)

**UPDATE**

The fix can be further improved by creating an alias for `vue` in the webpack config file:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
    }
}
```

That will make it possible to use `"vue"` again in the import statement, which then points to the `vue.esm-bundler.js` instead of the default `vue.runtime.es.js`.