# Need to embed vue component tags inside html file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Instead of making whole application in vue i want to use vue components inside html tags but the code i wrote is not working. Please help

I have executed applications with starting point as vue but i need help in this kind of application

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue'
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <hello-world></hello-world>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  
};
</script>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.29",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.29",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

I can do it with vue 2 but i am not able to do with vue 3

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
 Vue.component('hello-world', require('./HelloWorld.vue').default);
 new Vue({
     el: '#app',
 });
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
        "watch": "mix watch",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('src/main.js', 'dist')
    .vue();
```

Comment: "Not working" is not specific. Are there errors or warnings? Could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930544/working-vue-3-app-empties-mounted-element-when-using-vue-as-an-npm-package or anything else

Answer (score 1):

On the `main.js` file, where you mounted the app: just below the `const`, also use your Hello World Component:

```
app.component('hello-world', HelloWorld);
```

Copy and paste the below code to your `main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

    import App from './App.vue'
    import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue'
    
    const app = createApp(App)
    app.component('hello-world', HelloWorld);
    
    app.mount('#app')
```

Also, you wouldn't want to edit your public HTML, since you mounted your app to the DOM through the `#app`. Instead, call out the `HelloWorld` component in your `app.vue` file with its respective tags.

```
<template>
   <div> 
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is just a sample code i have to do this in an existing system.. where i cannot mount the App.vue but need to use vue components.

Comment: I wouldn't know under what circumstances this is applicable. What you need to do is install Vue into the existing system via Npm or Yarn. import Vue in a .js file

import { createApp } from 'vue' 

and also import your first parent-vue-component. 
import 'parent-component' from './parent-component.vue'

Mount that component for the specific HTML file through the #id 

createApp(parent-component).mount('#id')

and that should do it

Answer (score 0):

You should declare in Global Component on main.js

```
import ChildComponent from '..';

const app = createApp(App);
app.component("child-component", ChildComponent);
app.mount("#app");
```